# yii active record delete by composite primary key mysql

Tags: php, yii

I have table with composite primary key ('service_id', 'action_id'). This table was implemented as many2many relationship between action and service.

I can delete some record in another table by simple primary key like that:

```
ModelClass::model()->deleteByPk( 5 );
```

How can I delete record with composite primary key?

```
ModelClass::model()->deleteByPk( ? );
```

Comment: Use array for multiple primary keys. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#deleteByPk-detail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#deleteByPk-detail)

For one record:

```
ModelClass::model()->deleteByPk(array('service_id'=>xxxx,'action_id'=>yyyy));
```

For multiple records:

```
ModelClass::model()->deleteByPk(array(
  array('service_id'=>xxxx,'action_id'=>yyyy),
  array('service_id'=>xxxx,'action_id'=>zzzz),
  array('service_id'=>mmmm,'action_id'=>nnnn),
));
```

Answer (score 0):

pass an array to it with elements as keys

```
ModelClass::model()->deleteByPk(array('service_id'=>'value','action_id'=>'value'));
```